# "Все ходит по цепи кругом" — как это?

Tags: семантика, пушкин

Котяра оказался плодовит.
Никогда б не подумал, что даже по поводу выражения "по цепи кругом" может возникнуть столько оригинальных версий.

Вопрос. ***Опишите понятными словами подразумеваемое автором отношение "кота, дуба и цепи". 
Можно картинкой - из интернета.***

Я имею свой ответ, в коем абсолютно уверен. Дам позже.

Comment: @behemothus "Некогда" и "Никогда" это разные слова

Comment: >@behemothus "Некогда" и "Никогда" это разные слова  
  
Спасибо. У меня - "никогда"

Comment: >Я имею свой ответ, в коем абсолютно уверен. Дам позже.

Интересно было бы узнать и вашу версию.

Comment: Простите великодушно, пока - в самых ближайших планах. Обстоятельства не располагают.

Comment: Где же Ваша версия, behemothus?

Comment: @М_Г Тут какие-то чудеса творятся... Я хорошо помню, что где-то свою версию излагал. Действительно неудобно. Идею-то я помню, но сил восстанавливать все сейчас нет. Если пнете еще разок через недели две, может, сподоблюсь.

Comment: Хотя вы знаете, не такой уж я и недееспособный. Я начну завтра, коли интересно, пусть и сокращенную версию, но набросаю, если руки и глаза позволят. А там уже как получится. Чего я точно уже не найду, єто первоисточников, ну да ладно.

Answer (score 2):

Дополняя сказанное раннее, приведу следующую выдержку:

"Чем страшен Кот

Какова же функция Кота? Если бы ранг его был просто ранг наблюдателя, то Кот вызывал бы опасения, но не уважение, смешанное со страхом. Но, видимо, есть нечто, что отличает Кота от других «смотрящих». Оно, действительно – есть. У Кота есть страшная функция – он может нести смерть.
В колыбельной песенке, которую поют Бременские Музыканты в мультфильме, есть слова «придет серенький волчок и укусит за бочок». Волчок, как и положено оборотню, ничего интересного сделать не может – только тупо тяпнуть не желающего спать малыша. Но в оригинале песенка эта поется не так. Действует там не серенький волчок – можно подумать, что если страдающего бессонницей покусать, то он сразу же заснет – а совсем другой зверь, который сначала приглашается «нашу Лялю покачать». Это «серенький Коток». Кот поет песенку и погружает младенца в сон. Вспомним, что наши предки считали сон временной смертью. Но если младенец в сон не погружается, то Кот приступает к следующему пункту. Он тащит младенца «под ракитовый кусток», где мило кладет его в ямку. Что это такое, надеюсь, объяснять не надо.
Что же это за песни такие (и сказки! И сказки!), что к смерти ведут? А это потому, что Кот – это не просто кот, а Кот – Баюн с железными когтями (Помните «Пойди туда – не знаю куда»). Убаюкает и сердце вынет. Рыбаков его, правда, Велесом, скотьим богом обзывал и родственником Бояну, но это уже лишнее. Не связаны кошки с идолами, наоборот, попирают их («Лазают же по ним (идолам) также и кошки» - Иеремия).
А еще Кот защищает сирых и убогих. Вспомните – «Котик-братик, выручи меня!» И ведь выручил – убил Лису, а дочку ее – поленом по башке и в коробок, чтоб зараза не плодилась дальше. 
Лиса ведь - это не так просто. Этот зверь в мировой культуре символизирует поглотителя мира («Колобок», например, или тибетские сказки). Лиса хитрее Волка, она обманывает старика и старушку («Лисичка со скалочкой»), обижает Зайца, изгоняя его из лубяной избушки. Она – мировое Зло, тем более страшное, что естественное. А Кот наказывает это зло смертью, или, в сказке «Как Кот зверей напугал», женившись на Лисе, это зло нейтрализует, заменяя его упорядоченным налогообложением.

Что делает кот на дубе?

Остается ответить только на один вопрос – зачем Кот ходит по цепи? То, что это страшный Кот-Баюн, мы уже поняли. А вот что он делает на дубе?
И здесь надо вспомнить – где мы видели уже этот дуб с цепью? Не помните? А в сказках про Кощея. Это там стоит дуб, а на дубе – сундук, прикованный цепью, в котором хранится смерть Кощея. Этот-то сундук и охраняет Кот-Баюн, для этого там и русалка сидит, и леший бродит, и невиданные звери.
НО!
Мы уже сталкивались с тем, что Кот не олицетворяет собой Зло. Наоборот, он его карает, нейтрализует, восстанавливает порядок. И охрана сундука может в любой момент превратиться в свою противоположность. Поэтому, Кощей – заложник Кота. Зло не всесильно, смерть не вечна. Кто же побеждает смерть и зло. Тот, кто выше их, сильнее. То есть, тот, кому подвластен мир.
Поэтому я берусь утверждать, что в древнерусской мифологии Кот выступает в роли космогонического персонажа, равно распоряжающегося добром и злом, т.е. двуединым Богом (Инь-Янь)."

Источник: http://father-kot.livejournal.com/3752.html

Answer (score 2):

Мне вот этот старый советский мультфильм вспоминался, когда я писал в теме "Кот ученый".

Смотрите отрывок по ссылке. Дуб виден практически с самого начала. Кот НА цепи лучше всего виден приблизительно на 11-ой секунде. И на 2:36.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVw1Q5n9eDY

.

Вот ещё. Процитирую с одного [сайта](http://p-i-f.livejournal.com/5396094.html) :

Вот какую запись сделал Пушкин в Михайловском со слов няни Арины Родионовны: **«У моря лукомория стоит дуб, а на том дубу золотые цепи, и по тем цепям ходит кот: вверх идёт — сказки сказывает, вниз идёт — песни поёт».** Представляя содержание поэмы «Руслан и Людмила» как одну из сказок «кота учёного», Пушкин подчеркнул связь своего произведения с русским фольклором.

[image: Пушкин и кот ученый]

Answer (score 0):

На дубе дуб и дубом погоняет, сказители от дуба догоняют.
Не всякий дуб кота достоин, не всякий кот достоинством горазд.
А тот, кто цепью дуба не склоняет, тот дуба цепью не фантаст.