# Седьмой падеж "где?"

Tags: склонение, грамматика

Как правильно сказать: "в глазе" или "в глазу"? С одной стороны, это форма "в [ком/чём?]", то есть *предложный падеж*, тогда "в глазе". С другой стороны, есть седьмой падеж *где?*, и если просклонять "глаз" на сайте [Morpher](http://morpher.ru/Demo.aspx), там будет форма "в глазу". Меня смущает, что в школе мы не проходили этот падеж.

Можно ли писать "в глазе", или седьмой падеж здесь обязателен?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Окончания предложного падежа на **-у/-ю** для мужского рода (*в полку, в лесу, на берегу, на ветру*) и формы с переносом ударения на окончание для женского рода на **-ь** (*[вывалялся]в шерстИ, [широк] в костИ, [сидеть] на мелИ*) - это остатки т.н. ***локатива*** - особого "местного" падежа, почти совпавшего в современном языке с предложным. Этот падеж имел семантику места и/или причинности, возможно - и другую.

Характерен для определения места или причинности. Сейчас используется почти исключительно с предлогами **В** и **НА**, рудиментарно - с предлогом **О** ("О полку"), но ранее сочетался и с другими предлогами: с предлогом **ПО** ("по ком звонит колокол") и, вероятно, - **С** (*с цепИ [сорвалcя], с перепою*) и, возможно, другими. Сейчас эти конструкции превратились в особые формы других падежей: дательного, родительного и винительного.

См. например, здесь:
http://www.philology.ru/linguistics2/plungyan-02.htm

*Я подробнее остановлюсь на этих формах в своем вопросе о коте, дубе и ц**е**пи.*
["все ходит по цепи кругом". - как это?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/44727)
(+)
А вообще разные авторы (Зализняк, например) насчитывают до двенадцати русских "падежей", включая особые падежные формы. Помимо шести "школьных" и разбираемого **второго предложного** (локатива) есть еще **второй родительный** ("партитив" - [немного] чаю, сахару), **второй винительный** ([забрить] в солдаты, выйти в люди, "я в министры бы пощел"), **счетная форма** ("третий родительный": - пять ватт - не "ваттов"), **"новый звательный"** (Тань, мам).

забыл двенадцатый..., посмотрю. Или напомните.

Посмотрел. Еще **"лишительный"** и **"ждательный"**. Уже тринадцать.
Вот табличка хорошая.

http://nashol.com/2011060955536/tablica-padejei-russkogo-yazika.html

И это, видимо, не предел.

Answer (score 4):

Помимо шести падежей, о которых традиционно рассказывают в школьной программе, существуют падежи, традиционно не включённые в данный список, внесённые, согласно своим качествам, в шестёрку традиционных падежей. Так, существует так называемый "местный падеж", в котором, как правило, используется окончание "-у", в то время как предложному свойственно окончание "-е". Таким образом, имеем, что "в шкафу" является частным случаем местного падежа, а "в шкафе" — предложного. Говорить о том, какой из падежей "правильней" неверно. Использование того или иного окончания никак не зависит от контекста и определяется исключительно волей автора текста.

Кроме того, следует отметить, что местный падеж не является обязательным. Он включён в предложный падеж. Таким образом, при шестипадежной градации, оба окончания ("-е" и "-у") относят к предложному падежу. Это не ошибка, а упрощение.

Резюмируя сказанное: писать можно хоть "-у", хоть "-е".

Comment: Третий глаз, никто ме говорил, что местный падеж обязателен. Сейчас, естественно он включен в предложный падеж и не выделяется.

Comment: @Серж, я и не сказал, что это кто-то утверждает, а привёл как факт.

Answer (score 2):

Следует сказать, что ударное окончание **-у/ю** появляется в предложном падеже с предлогами *в* и *на* у некоторых **односложных существительных муж. рода 2 склонения**, преимущественно исконного происхождения (мост, день - *сто раз на дню*, пост, год, рот, борт, бой - в бою, бред, пруд, пот и др.). У существительных 1 и 3 скл.  такой особенности нет, поэтому выделять **специальный местный падеж** - нет никакой необходимости. Посудите сами : **в бою, в поту, в бреду** - какой же это местный падеж? Слова бой, бред, пот обозначают не местность, не территорию какую-то, чтобы на них распространять выдуманную некстати категорию М.п. Видимо, с безударным корнем в таких именно словах (2 скл., корень в один слог, м.р.) окончание П.п. **-у/ю** звучит на русский лад лучше, благозвучней, чем окончание **е**. Есть многие исключения (на дворе, на столе), поэтому вопрос чисто интуитивный по существу. Вопрос сложившегося за долгие годы словоупотребления.

Дополнение.
Окончания часто варьировались в одних и тех же словах. В лесУ - но "*в тёмном лЕсе*..." (песня), во всем мИре - но *в мирУ*, трудился *в пОте лица своего* - но проснулся в потУ, на *белом свЕте* - но на светУ и др. Предлоги и падежи те же самые, но смысл чуть разнится.
В иностранных словах не принято менять корневое ударение (на кОрте, на тОрте, на стАрте), однако в давно "прижившихся" словах ударение и окончание меняются (могут меняться) : в портУ, в цехУ, на газУ. Никаким особым падежом    такие окончания не объясняются, это именно **вариант произношения**. Простейший пример. Обычно говорят - *на белом свете*, но и по-другому в народе произносят :

> С. А. Есенин. Яр (1915)
>
> ― Помрет, ― сказала. ― **Не жилец на
> белом свету**. 
> Анна побледнела и
> ухватилась за сердце.

Comment: У меня ощущения, что слова бой, пот и бред в выражениях "в бою, в поту, в бреду" представляются как если бы они были трёхмерными объектами, в которых может находиться человек. Он умер в лесу -- он умер в бою.

Answer (score 2):

В современном русском языке  выделяется шесть падежей, **и не стоит умножать их количество.** Все падежи многозначны, но важнее выделить их центральное значение, чем дифференцировать по  значениям частным.

Например, Р.п. имеет две разновидности: партитивный  (количественно-разделительный) и отложительно-достигательный, но они связаны между собой  (сравнить: страница учебника и  страница из учебника).

Предложный падеж имеет две разновидности: изъяснительный и обстоятельственный (место, время, состояние: в лесу, на мосту, в цвету), значение П.п. выражают окончания Е и У/Ю.
Окончание Е – это основной вариант П.п. , при этом наблюдается общая тенденция к сокращению употребления формы У/Ю.

Окончание У/Ю:  только обстоятельственное значение, обычно односложные неодушевленные существительные,  стиль разговорный или поэтический, активно используется во фразеологизмах: в саду, на плоту, в цвету, как на духу, в отпуску. в цеху, в терему, на каждом шагу.

Окончание Е:  изъяснительное и обстоятельственное значение,  используется в свободных сочетаниях (реже во фразеологизмах), книжная речь, как односложные, так  и многосложные слова (в саду – в садике), при наличии прилагательного  окончание Е как основной вариант: в городе, на острове, в цехе, в отпуске, в тереме.

Про форму "в глазе"

Форма "в глазе" тоже используется, если имеется в виду объектное значение предмета (в чем, а не где):
И что ты смотришь на сучок в глазе брата твоего, а бревна в твоем глазе не чувствуешь? (Л. Н. Толстой. Воскресение).

Зеленый цвет здесь играет какую-то ролю; вспомним хорошенько; некоторые газы производят также в глазе ощущение зеленого цвета; эти газы имеют одуряющее свойство ― так точно! (В. Ф. Одоевский).

Answer (score 1):

В предложным падеже "глаз" имеет две формы: где? - в глазу; о чем?- о глазе. Это т.н. местный падеж, который выделяется в предложным падеже и употребляется только в сочетании с предлогами в и на в некоторых обстоятельствах времени и места: ***жить в лесу***.